# Excel Macro | adding two together

Tags: excel, vba

Complete New to this, I and trying to add 2 macros as one.  One that exports Excel to CVS and has a dialog box for file Name save and another file Dialog folder picker. assistance would be greatly appreciated

```
 Sub ExportAsCSV()

    Dim MyFileName As String
    Dim CurrentWB As Workbook, TempWB As Workbook

    Set CurrentWB = ActiveWorkbook
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy

    Set TempWB = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    End With

    MyFileName = CurrentWB.Path & "\" & Left(CurrentWB.Name, Len(CurrentWB.Name) - 5) & ".csv"

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    TempWB.SaveAs fileName:=InputBox("Enter file name here, : ", , xFileName), FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False, Local:=True
    TempWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

'''''''''''''''
'Plus file dialog 
'''''''''''''''''''''''

Sub SelectFolder()
    Dim diaFolder As FileDialog

    Set diaFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    diaFolder.AllowMultiSelect = False
    diaFolder.Show
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:= _
    diaFolder & ActiveSheet.[d2] & ".xlsx", FileFormat:= _
    xlExcel8, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False _
, CreateBackup:=False


    Set diaFolder = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you are asking how to pass variables. Search around for that, and how to create user-defined functions. You can change `SelectFolder` in to a function that returns a string (the folder path), then save from there for example.

Comment: What exactly is the expected behavior after adding them together?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little awkward because of the structure you propose. Normally, the name would be supplied by a function and acted upon by the calling procedure. Try to implement this structure in your project. Here is the function.

```
Private Function FolderName() As String

    Dim FilePicker      As FileDialog

    Set FilePicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With FilePicker
        .Title = "Select a target folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Documents\"
        .ButtonName = "Confirm"
        If .Show Then
            FolderName = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

And this is the part that should go into the calling procedure in some way.

```
Dim MyFolder As String

MyFolder = FolderName
If Len(MyFolder) Then MsgBox MyFolder
```

Of course, instead of the *MsgBox* your code would use the selected file name to actually save the workbook - code included in your *SelectFolder* procedure. The point is that no attempt to save the file is made if the user pressed *Cancel*. In that case the function returns an empty string which the calling procedure recognizes by the test of `Len(MyFolder)`.